# Why is a "nested-comment" not supported in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

In C++, the multi-line comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.

But it causes compile error if:

```
/*
int a = 20;
  /*
   int b = 10;

  */ 
*/
```

Is there any reason why C++ does not support this "nested-comment" style?

Comment: The inner `/*` doesn't count because it's commented out, so the outer `/*` "matches" with the inner `*/`.

Comment: What utility to you think this brings for C++ to support it?

Comment: I know it is not acceptable for compiler. But I want to know why C++ does not support it as another languages has no problem with it.

Comment: @StoryTeller You could easily comment out sections of code which already have block comments

Comment: @Unlikus what's wring with `#if 0` ...`#endif` for commenting out large sections? That's also less error prone. And, yes you can have any nesting levels you want

Comment: @Unlikus - That's not a feature for writing programs or making source code better.  And `#if 0 #endif` works well enough for that

Comment: Does C support this?

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, C doesn't allow nesting either.

Comment: *C++ does not support it as another languages has no problem with it.*  C++ is not those other languages.  Those are ... other languages.

Comment: are there any other languages that support this? I would find it extremely confusing, you would always have to read the full comment block to be sure that `/*` and `*/` are balanced. Maybe thats reason enough. Why make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: @Bathsheba I didn't DV, but "Why doesn't language X support Y?" is pretty much a useless question that tends to come across as more of a baseless rant.  "Why" is almost always subjective, and the number of unsupported features in any language is probably best approximated as infinite.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Hum. I used to moan about `> >` in templates pre C++11 when I was a little boy and would have posed exactly that question on Stack Overflow if it was around then. As for ranting, I think the OP is the epitome of temperance.

Comment: @user463035818 *Why make it more complicated than necessary?* Imagine the fun if the parser had to deal with embedded `//` lines that had a `*/` in them.  The more I think about it, the more I think nested comments are, umm, well, let's be kind and say they're not a good idea.

Comment: @Bathsheba *I think the OP is the epitome of temperance.*  Not really:  "Is there any **REASON** why ..."  That probably helped get a downvote or two.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Touche.

Comment: Short answer : because CPL did.   C++ inherited this style of comment with nesting forbidden from C, and the first C++ standard was explicitly required (terms of reference for developing the standard) to be backward compatible with C.   C inherited the same from a precursor language B, which inherited it from BCPL, which inherited it from CPL.  CPL dates from the 1960s, and most languages written at that time were designed to be fairly simple to parse, which probably explains why CPL did it that way.   Without access to documentation from that time, it would be impossible to speculate further.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know close to zero about parsers, I was rather worried about myself reading code / comments. Enabling this feature would make every multiline comment nested, meaning I would have to parse each comment in detail to know where it ends. I know there are IDEs and code highlighting, though I prefer to not rely on such features completely when it comes to reading my code

Comment: @AndrewHenle anyhow, I guess such kind of discussions is the reason the question got flagged as primarily opinion based ;)

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard states this regarding comments:

> **5.7 Comments [[lex.comment]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.comment)**
>   1 The characters `/*` start a comment, which terminates with the characters `*/`. **These comments do not nest.** The characters `//` start a comment, which terminates immediately before the next new-line character. If there is a form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such a comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required. [ Note: The comment
>   characters `//`, `/*`, and `*/` have no special meaning within a `//` comment and are treated just like other characters. **Similarly, the comment characters `//` and `/*` have no special meaning within a `/*` comment**.
>   —end note ]

Emphasis Added.

Since `/*` does not have any special meaning within a `/*` comment, the first `*/` following `/*` will be considered the end of the multi-line comment. Then the other `*/` will be considered to be dangling.

Comment: I think it is not so hard to speculate. Probably this is done to allow compilers to remove comments during lexer phase and not to worry later

Comment: @bartop: Yes. Trying to find some source to back this up.

Comment: Both variants would be equivalently easy to implement. And both are equvialently sane. So, the godfathers of C had to make a choice when C came out. Since then it was kept not to break existing code.

Comment: @bartop Specifically (for the benefit of other readers), if comments were allowed to nest, then lexing (aka tokenization) would not be parsing of a [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), but of a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). Apart from performance and maintainability considerations, the lexer generators available at the time, to my knowledge, only supported regular grammars. (Note that some extended "regexes", e.g. in Perl or ECMAScript, can match non-regular languages, and don't count.)

Comment: @ArneVogel You don't need all the machinery of CFG parsers to lex nested comments. All you need is an integer to track the depth.

Answer (score 1):

As with many missing but nonetheless easy to describe potential language features, this one is not in the C++ standard because nobody has managed to convince the relevant committee of its importance.

Yes it would occasionally be useful - such as when "binary chopping" a program by inserting comment blocks to hunt down a memory leak or other issue.

I can't think of a theoretical reason why it couldn't be allowed insofar that I can't think of any existing code that could break should this feature be introduced.

Note one obscurity though: `/**/` can be used in place of a space in some places (e.g. `int/**/n;`); the meaning of `/*/**/*/` would need to be thought through.

Why not propose it?

Comment: "binary chopping" can be achieved by using `#ifdef UNDEFINED_SYMBOL` as well, no problem with nesting for those afaik

Comment: @user463035818: Indeed there are alternatives and we all have our favourites, but C and C++ in particular are intentionally flexible.

Comment: There are compilers that can be configured to support nested `/*` - `*/` style of comments.   Code which uses nested comments either does not compile OR compiles to something different with compilers that don't support nested comments.